# How to transfer half of the array to another array with different size?

Tags: c++

For example, I have an array: int arr1[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}. I want to transfer all values in the odd position to another array: int arr2[5] = {1,3,5,7,8}.

Comment: In what part of your code are you stuck?

Comment: I really don't have any idea on how to start

Comment: try this [code](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/operator[]/) as a starting point

Comment: Consider changing the arr2[5]={1,3,5,7,8} to arr2[5]={1,3,5,7,9}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is quick fix for you. Check following code.

```
    int array[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int newArray[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i+=2) {
        newArray[j] = array[i];
        cout << newArray[i] << endl;
        j++;
    }
```

Hope this solution works.

Comment: Thank youuuuuuuuuuuuu!!

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll have to allocate the appropriate amount of memory to the second array. Then, a simple for loop should do the job.

```cpp
// This loops over all odd positions in arr1.
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i += 2)
{
    arr2[i/2] = arr1[i];
}
```

But I believe you want to handle this for arbitrary size. Try to come up with the correct allocations to the new array. If you're stuck, let me know.

But try to include what you've already tried.